# Enabling direct content creation in XAML on a dependancy object

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, dependencyobject

I have a class `CollectionOfThings`.  As its name suggests its a simple collection of instances of the `Thing` class.  `Thing` class has a public default constructor and two simple public get, set properties `ID` and `DisplayName`, both are string.  `CollectionOfThing` also has public default constructor.

In XAML I would like to use markup like this:-

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:CollectionOfThings x:Key="Things">
        <local:Thing ID="1" DisplayName="Hello" />
        <local:Thing ID="2" DisplayName="World" />
    <local:CollectionOfThings>
</Grid.Resources>
```

All is good as long as CollectionOfThings derives from a Collection type.  However I want `CollectionOfThings` to also be a `DependencyObject`.  I thought that's fine creating an implementation of `ICollection<T>`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` etc is not that hard.  Then I can derive from `DependencyObject`.

Unfortunately `ICollection<T>` doesn't cut it for some reason.  With `ICollection<Thing>` I get 'CollectionOfThings does not support Thing as content'. Go back to `Collection<Thing>` and everything works but leaves me without a `DependencyObject` implementation.

Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XAML wants `System.Collections.IList` (the non-generic one!) for collections. If you only implement generic `IList<T>` interface, it won't cut it.

It also expects to see public `Add` methods on the class, and derives suitable child types for the collection from arguments of those methods. So the typical approach is to explicitly implement `IList` - so that its `Add(object)` method isn't public, and thus isn't picked by XAML parser - and then implicitly implement `IList<T>` for all child types that you want to support.

The reason why it works for most built-in collection types (`List<T>`, `Collection<T>` etc) is because they follow the pattern above and implement both generic and non-generic interfaces.

Comment: Thats got it!  The vanilla IList was what I was missing, thanks.

Comment: Perfect answer, I expected to use IList<T> thinking it would be preferred to List<T>, now thanks to this post I know why and am happy with using List<T> as the property type. I get the design-time support I was missing with IList

Answer (score 5):

Collections are usually used in xaml so as to define a `ContentPropertyAttribute("PropertyName")` on the custom class where `PropertyName` is usually `IList` or `IList<T>`.

```
[ContentProperty(SomeProp)]
class SomeClass
{
    //this is where subitems created in xaml would get added automatically
    public IList<int> SomeProp { get; set; } 
}
```

However, if a class does not provide a value for the `ContentPropertyAttribute`, and implements any interface of type `IList<T>`, `IList`, `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`, a property of name "Items" (if present, and if of appropriate type, e.g. `IList`) is detected trough reflection automatically (for the purpose of population trough xaml), and that is the case with the `Collection<T>` class.

You can even check the class in Reflector to make sure it has no content property defined.

The `Collection<T>` class has this property

```
protected IList<T> Items
{
    get
    {
        return _items;
    }
}
```

and adding something like that to your collection type (even if the property is protected) is enough to have it behave as desired in xaml.

I suppose the behavior is implemented in that way for backward compatibility.

Comment: @kky444: Thanks for the response.  However as I stated in my question I'm implementing ICollection<Thing> already yet that doesn't seem to help.  I've tried also implementing IList<Thing> and exposing an Items property with a ContentProperty attribute decorating the class.  None of this above works. (BTW IList is a ICollection not the other way around).

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: okay, to recap, do not set the content property, use IList<Thing>, expose an Items property of type IList<Thing>, and this WILL work, I've just checked it. The xaml editor may argue, that is true, but it will build.